# Input variable in Where clause for SQL "Select Statement" - Access, VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Need help for the below listed issues.

1. I am **getting "YearN" as user input** to the select statement to Run a Query in VBA for Access Database. The statement **works when a number directly entered** in where clause say "2027". **Not sure how to reference a input variable/object**. Please help.
2. Need help to refresh the record as I am getting **runtime error** whenever the code trying to execute line `"A.open strconnection"` saying *"The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine  that prevents it from being opened or locked"*. Please advise

````
Dim YearNumber As Long
DoCmd.RefreshRecord
YearN = InputBox("Enter the Record Year to delete:")
    
If YearN = "" Then
MsgBox "Year not entered. Query exit"
Else
Dim A As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Set A = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\OneDrive - fab\Access_Db\file.Accdb"
strSql = "DELETE FROM APAC_tbl_test WHERE Year= YearN;"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
A.Open strConnection
Set rs = A.Execute(strSql)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Set rs = Nothing
A.Close
Set A = Nothing
End If
End Sub```
````

Comment: Why do you need to create an additional connection to the database? Can you not juse use `CurrentDB`? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.currentdb

Comment: The problem is that you have that database open exclusively in the copy of Access you have open, and you are then trying to create an additional connection to it (which means you cannot connect because it's opened exclusively already), and there is no need for that unless you are leaving something out of your question.

Comment: Sorry.. I am pretty new to Access & vba. I get what you meant, creating an additional connection doesn't make any sense. I went through the link you specified.. Current DB can be used. Thanks. I would really appreciate you can help me with my first question  to how to get the user input and run a sql query

Comment: `strSql = "DELETE FROM APAC_tbl_test WHERE Year= " & YearN`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have a "pop-up" box where the user inputs a value for the `WHERE` clause within Access, you don't necessarily need VBA code. Simply write your SQL statement and in the `WHERE` clause you'll do something like below:

```
DELETE FROM APAC_tbl_test WHERE Year = [Enter Year:]
```

Once you run the above code it should prompt user for the year with "pop-up" box that is labelled "Enter Year".

So basically,

```
WHERE [column name] = [custom prompt message:]
```

Important to keep the brackets `[ ]` and the semicolon `:`.

More information can be found at this link - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed